# Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance' required by parameter 'InputObject'

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

Iam trying to create a powershell script that removes accounts if they have not been logged in on the workstation windows 10 after a certain amounts days.

This script is going *to be run locally and not remote*.
I think that iam very close to the solution but by some reason even if i do as the documentation @ microsoft shows, iam not able to remove the accounts with the parameter inputobject.

For example iam trying to remove Account 3 and 2, because they have the similar LastUseTime Date.

**Account - LastUseTime**

```
testuser3 - 20190625   
testuser2 - 20190625   
testuser1 - 20190629
```

**Code :**

```
<# Change Value to remove account after a certain days #>
     $DaysFilterAccounts = (get-date (Get-Date).AddDays(-6) -UFormat "%Y%m%d")

<# $CheckLastUseTime
   Get all UserProfiles, Filter Service and Admin-accounts
   Select and convert LastUsetime to a date object
   Where only accounts lastusetime is Less Or Equal to $DaysFilterAccounts
#>
     $CheckLastUseTime = Get-CimInstance -Filter "Special=False AND Loaded=False" -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | 
     Select-Object @{Name="LastUseTime";Expression={Get-Date $_.Lastusetime -Format "yyyyMMdd" } } | 
     Where-Object { $_.LastUseTime -Le $DaysFilterAccounts } 

<# Create a String for Lastusetime #>
     $AccountLastUseTime = $CheckLastUseTime.Lastusetime 

<# 
   ForEach-Object In $GetProfiles If .LastUsetime is Less Or Equal to $DaysFilterAccounts
   Then Get the UserProfile Data And 
   Remove Profiledata 
#>

   If ( $AccountLastUseTime -Le $DaysFilterAccounts ) 
   {  
      $RemoveTheseAccounts = Get-CimInstance -Filter "Special=False AND Loaded=False" -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | 
      Select-Object Sid, Localpath, @{Name="LastUseTime";Expression={Get-Date $_.Lastusetime -Format "yyyyMMdd" }} |
      Where-Object { $_.LastUseTime -Le $DaysFilterAccounts } 

      Remove-CimInstance -InputObject $RemoveTheseAccounts



} Else {   Write-Warning -Message "Error"    }
```

**Error Mess:**

```
Remove-CimInstance : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance' 
required by parameter 'InputObject'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:\Users\fardin.TEST\Desktop\Rolf v 3.ps1:52 char:39
+       Remove-CimInstance -InputObject $RemoveTheseAccounts
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-CimInstance], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.RemoveCimInstanceCommand
```

**Solution:**

```
<# Change Value to remove account after a certain days #>
$DaysFilterAccounts = (get-date (Get-Date).AddDays(-180) -UFormat "%Y%m%d") 

<# $CheckLastUseTime
   Get all UserProfiles, Filter Service and Admin-accounts
   Select and convert LastUsetime to a date object
   Where only accounts lastusetime is Less Or Equal to $DaysFilterAccounts
#>
$CheckLastUseTime = Get-CimInstance -Filter "Special=False AND Loaded=False" -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | 
Select-Object @{Name="LastUseTime";Expression={Get-Date $_.Lastusetime -Format "yyyyMMdd" } } | 
Where-Object { $_.LastUseTime -Le $DaysFilterAccounts } 

<#  Create a String for Lastusetime #>
$AccountLastUseTime = $CheckLastUseTime.Lastusetime

<# 
   ForEach-Object In $GetProfiles If .LastUsetime is Less Or Equal to $DaysFilterAccounts
   Then Get the UserProfile Data And 
   Remove Profiledata 
#>
   If ( $AccountLastUseTime -Le $DaysFilterAccounts ) 
   {  

        # Remove Profiles
        $GetUserProfileData = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -Filter "Special=False AND Loaded=False" | 
        Where { $_.LastUseTime -Le $DaysFilterAccounts }                 
        $GetUserProfileData  | Remove-WmiObject 


} Else {   Write-Warning -Message "Error"    }
```

Comment: Change it to `$RemoveTheseAccounts |Remove-CimInstance` and let pipeline binding take care of the rest

Comment: I remember that i tried that before, lets test with "|"

Remove-CimInstance : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does 
not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At C:\Users\fardin.TEST\Desktop\Rolf v 3.ps1:52 char:30
+       $RemoveTheseAccounts | Remove-CimInstance
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{Sid=S-1-5-21-...eTime=20190625}:PSObject) [Remove-CimInstance], Parame 
   terBindingEx..

Answer (score 6):

A little explanation here, teach a person to fish etc. By convention: the InputObject property refers to the current property in the pipe and usually means you should pipe the object in.
Running `Get-Help Remove-CimInstance -Parameter InputObject` shows you the reason for your error:

```
-InputObject <CimInstance>
    Specifies a CIM instance object to be removed from the CIM server. 

    Note: The input object passed to the cmdlet is not changed, only the instance in the CIM server is removed.

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    1
    Default value                none
    Accept pipeline input?       True (ByValue)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

From the help documentation you can see that InputObject takes in a **single** object of type **CimInstance**, so giving it an array of **CimInstance[]** is not valid. You can also see that it accepts pipeline input. This gives you two choices. You can either loop through the object in a foreach block (not recommended), or pipe the object into the function. This will call the `process` block on Remove-CimInstance for each of the items in the array; passing an object of type **CimInstance** for each entry.

As Mathias has stated, the following should fix the issue:

```
$RemoveTheseAccounts | Remove-CimInstance
```

More information on the process block (as well as the begin and end blocks) can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-6#process